# Google Spreadsheet Script Help - Column Loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script which takes an email address, role, and group email address and adds it to a Google Apps group.  I have it currently working for one row only.  How can I have it work for many (i.e. 25) rows without having an individual script for all of them?  The script is listed here:

```
function addGroupMember() {
  var userEmail = getUser();
  var groupEmail = getGroup();
  var member = {
   email: userEmail,
   role: getRole()
  };
  member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
  Logger.log('User %s added as a member of group %s.', userEmail, groupEmail);
  }

function getUser() {
  user = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2').getValue();
  return user }

function getRole() {
  role = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B2').getValue();
  return role }

function getGroup() {
  group = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A27').getValue();
  return group }
```

Thanks for the help!

-Joe

Comment: Looks like you are learning to program. This is not a "learn to program" site. There are lots of good sites for that, see blog.ted.com/2013/01/29/10-places-where-anyone-can-learn-to-code/

Comment: Actually, I've done a fair amount of Javascript before.  I just don't know how to do a for loop with multiple functions.  How can I do that?

Comment: Joe, suggest you take the time to understand for loops and functions. It is a bit like understanding 1+1. You either understand, or you don't. And guessing how to add numbers together, or do loops, does not get you very far. The example tutorials on the web are very good and designed to help you learn. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding the cell values in your `getWhatever()` functions, use a parameter that can be looped. For example:

```
function getUser(row) {
  // "User" is in column A, aka column 1
  user = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1).getValue();
  return user }
```

Looks like `getGroup` remains as-is, as every user is in the same group.

Paramterize your `addGroupMember` function:

```
function addGroupMember(row) {
  var userEmail = getUser(row);
  var groupEmail = getGroup(row);
  var member = {
   email: userEmail,
   role: getRole()
  };
  member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
  Logger.log('User %s added as a member of group %s.', userEmail, groupEmail);
  }
```

Then you can do this:

```
function addAll() {
  // assume users in rows 2 - 26, since you may have headers, and row 27 has group
  for (var row=2; row<=26; row++) {
    addGroupMember(row);
  }
}
```

There's still plenty of improvement needed here, mainly for performance reasons.